# Haskell Function to get minimum of a list depending on a given function

Tags: function, haskell

I have to write a function like this minByFunction (\x -> -x) [1,2,3,4,5] that gives me as an answer 5. Another example would be minBy length ["a", "abcd", "xx"] gives me "a".
I though I can solve this with something like this:

```
minBy :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
minBy measure list =
  case list of
    [] -> 0
    (x:xs:rest) -> if measure x > measure xs then minBy measure x:rest else minBy measure xs:rest
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MichaelLitchard What part of that page do you think is applicable here? The title seems fine, there's a description of the problem, non-working code that represents the current attempt, example failing input and desired output. It was formatted badly, but Willem fixed that before your comment, and it would have been easy to fix yourself as well (the source was indented properly, just not marked as code).

Comment: @amalloy yep. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use parenthesis for `(x:rest)`, otherwise it is interpreted as `(minBy measure x) : rest`. Since the two recursive calls have `minBy measure` in common, we can however make a `if … then … else …` clause for the list with which we make a recursive call.

Furthermore the `measure` should not *per se* return a `Bool`, you want to map it on any type `b` that is a member of the `Ord` typeclass.

You also swapped the recursive calls: in case `measure x < measure xs`, then you should recurse with `x:rest` and vice versa.

Finally the function should return an `a` object, so the base case is a *singleton* list, not an empty list: for an empty list there is no minimum:

```
minBy :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
minBy measure list =
  case list of
    [x] -> x
    (x:x2:xs) -> minBy measure (if measure x > measure x2 then x2:xs else x:xs)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `measure` function does not return a `Bool`. In both of the examples you gave, the `measure` function returns an `Int`. Also, the final return value of `minBy` is not necessarily an `Int`. It is a value with the same type as the elements of the list. So if you give the `minBy` function a list of strings, the returned value will be a string. With these two considerations in mind, the type signature of `minBy` should be:

```
minBy :: (a -> Int) -> [a] -> a
```

This is not the most general type, however. The value returned by the `measure` function doesn't have to be an `Int`, it can also be a `Double` or a `String` or anything comparable. The way to express that a value is comparable is with the `Ord` constraint.

```
minBy :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
```

In the first branch of the `case` expression, you define the minimum value of an empty list to be 0. This definition will fail to type-check. The minimum value of a list must have the same type as the elements of the list, and the type annotation for `minBy` states that you can give a list of any type, not just a list of integers.

Defining the minimum value of an empty list to be 0 also conflicts with the definition of "minimum value." The empty list doesn't *have* a minimum value; it has no values at all! A better base case would be: "if the list has just one element, the minimum value is that element."

```
case list of
  [x] -> x
```

The second branch of your `case` expression is almost correct; you just need to replace `>` with `<`. The first element should be kept if its measure is *smaller* than the second element's. You also need to surround `x:rest` in parentheses, because the `:` operator has lower precedence than function calls. `minBy measure x:rest` will be parsed as `(minBy measure x) : rest`, which is not what you want.

```
minBy :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
minBy measure list =
  case list of
    [x] -> x
    x:y:rest -> 
      if measure x < measure y 
        then minBy measure (x:rest) 
        else minBy measure (y:rest)
```

I also replaced the variable you called `xs` with `y`, because the name `xs` in Haskell is normally used for lists.